# Paperclip not saving image, only creadted_at and updated_at getting stored and everything else is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, rails-api

I am developing an **rails api only app**. I have integrated paper-clip but upon saving with POSTMAN and CURL both I get response as success, the record gets created but only created_at & updated_at fields get saved everything else remains nil.
**If I create the record on console everything works fine.** 
Model

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :image, :image_attributes
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:medium =>"300x300"}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Controller

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        picture = Picture.new
    end

    def create
        print 'dir is'
    puts Dir.pwd
    result = { status: "failed" }

    begin
      picture = Picture.new 
      if picture.valid? && picture.save
        result[:status] = "success"
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      Rails.logger.error "#{e.message}"
    end

    render json: result.to_json
  ensure
    clean_tempfile
  end


  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:title,:image)
  end

    def parse_image_data(image_data)
      @tempfile = Tempfile.new('item_image')
      @tempfile.binmode
      @tempfile.write Base64.decode64(image_data[:content])
      @tempfile.rewind

      uploaded_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
        tempfile: @tempfile,
        filename: image_data[:filename]
      )

      uploaded_file.content_type = image_data[:content_type]
      uploaded_file
    end

  def clean_tempfile
    if @tempfile
      @tempfile.close
      @tempfile.unlink
    end
  end
end
```

My server log trace.

```
Started POST "/pictures?title=new" for ::1 at 2016-01-13 22:26:04 +0530
Processing by PicturesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004924b50 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160113-3226-brqash.png>, @original_filename="philosphy.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"philosphy.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "title"=>"new"}
dir is/home/anjan/Development/frankly_speak
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `pictures` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-01-13 16:56:04', '2016-01-13 16:56:04')
   (38.2ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 40.0ms)
```

Comment: where is call to `#parse_image_data`?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Hi, Dont know where to call it, can you guide me please?

Comment: I dont know the paperclip should proceed the uploaded image itself. how to do it please refer to paperclip manuals

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Since it is an API only app with no form to do http-multipart I guess I have to encode it in base64 then attempt to save in DB. If am wrong please correct me

Comment: paperclip just stores uploaded image in the specific folder or reuploads it to a cloud... but keeping the url path to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
picture = Picture.new
```

to

```
picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
```

in `create` action

Comment: doing that only saves the title of the image but not the image itself.